# Unknown server tag 'dnn:DnnCssInclude'

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-settings

I want to develop project using DNN and installed DNN 8.0.0 with VS2010, it works fine on browser with the Admin panel as it is CMS. But I want my customize my site so i have loaded source code at the VS2010 and while going to build it, it shows me error for

> unknown server tag 'dnn:DnnCssInclude'

and

> unknown server tag 'dnn:DnnJsInclude'

on the folder path: \dnndemo\Portals_default\Skins\Xcillion\Common\AddFiles.ascx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please add the following line to your code in the following file.

'PROJECTFOLDER'\Portals_default\Skins\YOURSKINNAME\Common\AddFiles.ascx

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>
```